# Openui5: Change renderer for component during runtime?

Tags: sapui5

I'm investigating some novel approaches to extending openui5. 
Particularly I'm playing around with the idea of implementing material design with openui5 (through material design lite https://github.com/google/material-design-lite). Normally, you would extend existing components with new ones, but I want to avoid this if possible.

One approach would be to dynamically change the renderer of a component during runtime. I want to change the renderer for a particular instance of a component and not all instances.

I've found that through the MetaData of the control, I can change overwrite the render function

```
myComponent.getMetadata().getRenderer().render = function(oRm, oControl) {
...
};
myComponent.rerender();
```

This gives the intended effect. However, using this approach changes the renderer for all instances of the component class.

Is there some way of only changing the renderer for a particular instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in the standard controls that come as part of the framework, the *Renderer for each control is a static class - this is why the control instance is passed in to the render() method. This is why re-defining the render method, as you did it, affects all control instances of this type.

Sneaking into metadata.getRenderer() and returning something different for this instance would cause similar issues, as ElementMetadata is also one instance for the entire control class. Cloning the metadata and modifying it for certain instances would be an option, but I think not a nice one.

Maybe a simple solution is the best choice here?
Mark the control instances to be rendered differently with a flag and overwrite the render method to either do the normal thing or do the special handling, depending on this flag.

Something like this:
http://jsbin.com/yabujigitu/edit?html,output